# How do I extract an Object (or Array) from a Promise-object that was returned by an Async/Await function?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

### Problem

I am having trouble accessing an array of data contained within a Promise{} object that has been returned by an Async/Await function.

I know that Async/Await is a wrapper for Promises, and therefore, it will always return a promise. I'm just unable to get to the data inside.

*I've researched this extensively and haven't even seen a reference to the kind of output I'm seeing.*

---

### Code

Here is the contents of an image directory:

```
outside3.jpg
outside2.png
outside1.jpg
matt.png
truck.png
```

Let's say I'm trying to get that list of items contained within the directory.

```
const fs = require('fs');

/* The files are here */
const imgPath = "../public/images/client/carousel2/" 

const getFileList = async (filePath)=>{
    let fileList = [];
    const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(filePath);

    for await (const dirent of dir) {
        fileList.push(dirent.name)
    }

    return fileList
}

let fileNames = getFileList(imgPath)

setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(fileNames)
}, 500);
```

### Output

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
Promise {
  [
    'outside3.jpg',
    'outside2.png',
    'outside1.jpg',
    'matt.png',
    'truck.png'
  ]
}
```

---

### Question

While there may be a better way to go about getting the contents of a directory, my question pertains more to the `Promise` object being returned by the Async/Await function.

Given the output, how do I extract the Array from this `Promise` object?

Or, if that's the wrong question, how do I return only an Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid approach is to create an asynchronous function to be your "main" function, so you just call it and it can contain any asynchronous logic you've written.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

/* The files are here */
const imgPath = "../public/images/client/carousel2/" 

const getFileList = async (filePath)=>{
    let fileList = [];
    const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(filePath);

    for await (const dirent of dir) {
        fileList.push(dirent.name)
    }

    return fileList
}

const main = async () => {
  let fileNames = await getFileList(imgPath)
  console.log(fileNames)
}

main()
```

This will return the array which resulted from the promise:

```
[
  'outside3.jpg',
  'outside2.png',
  'outside1.jpg',
  'matt.png',
  'truck.png'
]
```

Comment: I've been struggling with async in javascript. I even went as far back as callbacks to try to understand the evolution of async, but it still wasn't clicking. Your answer confirms my suspicions and helped me fill in the gaps of my knowledge. Thanks Telmo

Answer (score 0):

This will be better solution for you.

```
const fs = require('fs');

/* The files are here */
const imgPath = "../public/images/client/carousel2/" 

const files = fs.readdirSync(imgPath);
console.log(files);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I was already looking at the `fs.readdirSync` function as a possible solution for my program. But my aim here was to try to better understand Async/Await.